# java.lang.NullPointerException | My clock doesn't work

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

A friend of mine and I have to program a game in java for university. I'm trying to implement a little clock in our toolbar we created. When I run the Code, this error shows up:

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   GameTimer.run(GameTimer.java:29)

KodeKsToolBar.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;

import javax.swing.*;

public class KodeKsToolBar extends JToolBar{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static JLabel timeLabel;

    public KodeKsToolBar(GUI listener, Dimension size){
        //unimported Stuff hidden
        //...   
        JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel(GameTimer.currentTime);
        GameTimer t = new GameTimer();
        t.start();
        //clock = new Clock(this);
        //clock.start();

        setFloatable(false);
        add(ToolBarItem_NGame);
        add(ToolBarItem_Load);
        add(ToolBarItem_Save);
        add(ToolBarItem_Resign);
        add(toolBarItem_PauseResume);
        add(timeLabel);
    }
}
```

GameTimer.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;



public class GameTimer extends Thread {
    static boolean running = true;
    int milliSeconds = 0;
    int seconds = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    static String currentTime = "00:00";

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            milliSeconds++;
            if(milliSeconds > 999){
                milliSeconds = 0;
                seconds++;
            }
            if(seconds > 59){
                seconds = 0;
                minutes++;
            }
            KodeKsToolBar.timeLabel.setText(getTime()); // <-- This is the line mentioned above, which causes the error
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getTime() {
        currentTime = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        return currentTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the code that is not relevant to your error.

Comment: Which line is `GameTimer.java:29`?

Comment: You initialize the static ``timeLabel`` in the constructor (which does not make too much sense by the way). When the NPE occurs, the constructor has not been called obviously.

Comment: @ssantos it is marked in code: `KodeKsToolBar.timeLabel.setText(getTime());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're accessing a static variable

```
KodeKsToolBar.timeLabel
```

but initializing a local variable with the same name in `KodeKsToolBar` constructor

```
JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel(GameTimer.currentTime);
```

Remove `JLabel` to leave just.-

```
timeLabel = new JLabel(GameTimer.currentTime);
```

PS: as @Overcraft Full of Eels stated, remember that your instance variables should be non-static, except the constants (the ones declared as `final`).

Comment: @tk4muffin that you are creating and initializing new local `JLabel timeLabel` variable in `KodeKsToolBar` constructor instead of `KodeKsToolBar.timeLabel`.

Comment: Glad you did it :) Remember consider upvoting/accepting an answer you found useful, so other users can easily spot it. Cheers!

Comment: Can you also tell me how I'm able to run a thread from another class? I got my thread in KodeKsToolBar and I want to be able to pause and resume the timer from the GameTimer class.

Comment: Mmh I'm a little confused here, isn't `GameTime` the `Thread` you're talking about?

Comment: Anyway, it would be clearer if you ask a new question for this, as it's out of the scope of the original one. You'll also find the right answer quicker.

Answer (score 2):

You're shadowing the timeLabel variable by *re-declaring a variable **of the same name*** in the constructor. This means that you initialize only the variable declared to the constructor but not the one located and declared in the class. Don't re-declare timeLabel in the constructor but rather declare it only once in the class.

Also note that this variable should **not** be static, not by a long shot. In fact all of your static variables, with the exception of any constants, should not be static but should be instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

You assigning `static` class variable, so you need:

```
timeLabel = new JLabel(GameTimer.currentTime);
```

You need this because  leaving `JLabel` creates another object and class member is not initialized. Compiler should warn about such situation.

BTW static variables is like global constants for given class, you should take a look and determine if you really need that.

Comment: Not only should he look, but the involved field should *not* be static.